# Design is messed up in IE9

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer

I'm working on a new website, it's using jQuery and CSS3 elements, and it's working well in Firefox, Chrome and other browsers; however it's not getting messed up in IE

The link to my website is http://www.sy-architects.com/test. Could please take a look at it? I suspect it's something to do with the bottom menu and `<ul>` markup but am not sure.

EDIT: If you mouse over on the menu Practice People or Projects you will notice that the design is messed up the bottom bar is on the top and the rest of the `<li>` is showing on top instead of the menu itself and it's getting weird, plz check it on both Firefox and IE to see the difference, I'm using IE9 by the way

Comment: It's working perfectly fine on my IE9. When does it crash? What IE version? Be more specific please.

Comment: Whats the error that you get?  Or incorrect behavior?

Comment: Jared actually it's not an error, it's just not displaying well on IE, I was trying to find out what's making the problem it worked well before but since I added an additional `<ul>` and `<li>` tags to the menu it messed up everything I tried to remove them yet the problem still there !

Comment: So wait, are you having ACTUAL crashes (e.g. browser closes) or your design is simply messed up?

Comment: I'll remove my answer as it's not related to design flaws. You should tag your question with `css` if it's just the way your page displays and not actual crashes.

Comment: Sorry Fabricio I've edited the question, it's related to design flaws, I'm new to StakOverFlow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would remove this:

```
    <meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
```

No reason to move the website down to make IE9 work like IE8.  There are some display issues on IE9, but that should be easily fixable once you test it.

Second, you should [validate the HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.sy-architects.com/test/) , there were 16 errors, some of which were layout issues (elements were not closed, particularly in the nav menus a lot of LIs were not closed properly.  While not all are serious, the layout issues could cause crashes particularly in older browsers with poor parsing engines (like IE7).

Other than that, I didn't see any crashes in IE7, just layout issues.  Fixing the HTML markup should go a long way towards fixing the layout.

Comment: Looks like the question was edited/commented to while I was responding.  Since there aren't crashes, that makes validating even more important, and getting the HTML structure correct.

Comment: Actually the problem is due to `<ul>` and `<li>` not closing properly..Thanks for the help

Comment: Yup, that was what I noticed, glad that fixed it.  That's why I recommended validating a site - I'm not a validation nut, but I use it all the time as a debug tool as it'll quickly point out a missing closing tag or a typo.